# Python Beam Airflow not creating BigQuery partitioned table

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, airflow-scheduler, google-cloud-composer

I have a beam pipeline where I ingest data from file, clean it and write to BigQuery partitioned table

```
(delivered
| 'delivered to json' >> beam.Map(to_json)
| 'write delivered' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
                                   delivered_table_spec,
                                   schema=table_schema,
                                   create_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED,
                                   write_disposition=beam.io.BigQueryDisposition.WRITE_APPEND,
                                   additional_bq_parameters={'timePartitioning': {'type': 'DAY'}}
))
```

If I run above pipeline directly on Dataflow, everything happens as expected i.e. data gets cleaned and written to BigQuery table partitioned on date per day. However, when I try to schedule the same script using Cloud Composer (Airflow), a simple table gets created instead of a partitioned table. Am I missing something? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this running in batch or streaming mode?

Comment: As of now, this is reading from google storage bucket, so it is mostly batch

Comment: When you read bigquery's query history, is the `CREATE TABLE` statement coming from Dataflow?  Or is some other task in creating it?